# Extracting balls from an urn with balls of different colours and the r.v. is "different colours"

Tags: probability

I have the following problem: I have $3$ balls from color $A$, $2$ from $B$, and $1$ from $C$. I want to find the elements of the muestral space of $X$: "different colours". I extract $2$ balls. So the probabilities would be

$$P[x = \text{equal colours}]=\frac{\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}$$

$$P[x = \text{different colours}]=\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{ 1}}{\binom{6}{2}}$$

It's that right?

Thanks.

Comment: Do they add up to 1?

Comment: You have not accounted for the possibility that the ball of colour $C$ is extracted.